# Android Navigation with Up Button from activity with multiple entry points

Tags: android, navigation, notifications, android-pendingintent

I am implementing an up button in a music player app. The player activity for this app can have numerous points of entry (multiple tracklists in different activities). I am trying to figure out how to implement the up button pattern correctly. According to the docs:

> Navigating to screens with multiple entry points
>
> Sometimes a screen doesn't have a strict position within the app's hierarchy, and can be >reached from multiple entry points—such as a settings screen that can be reached from any >other screen in your app. In this case, the Up button should choose to return to the >referring screen, behaving identically to Back.

That makes sense, under normal usage, I would just call onBackPressed() or even finish(). But there is one case I don't know how to handle. Playback occurs in a service with a notification. If the user backs out of the app while something is playing, he/she can click on the notification to go directly to the player.

At this point, the player would be the only thing in the stack, so I am not sure the best way to proceed when the user clicks up. Ideally, I would like to pick a default landing page (home page) to navigate to. I am unsure how to know where to send the user without looking at the backstack though, and there seems like there should be something easier.

So I am looking for a way for this sequence:

```
- user is in player activity and presses up
- if the entry point to the player is still on the backstack, I finish() to go back to the referring activity
- if the entry point is not on the backstack, I go to the home page
```

Does this sound right, and further is there any easy way to implement this?

Comment: sounds like you need to make an artificial back stack?